# Delay model change when editing cells in Angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When editing a cell in a `ui-grid`, the underlying model changes immediately (before committing the change by pressing Enter). Pressing escape undoes the change (by setting the model to the original value).

I have a `$watch` set on the model, it fires with every keystroke, including the cancel event. I would like the model to only change when the change is committed in the grid.

My work-around is to not have a watch, and use a combination of `gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit` and firing events when action buttons (custom templates in cells) are pressed - but that is not a very graceful solution.

Is there any way to coerce `ui-grid` to delay updating the model until after the cell changes are committed?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way built in, currently, as the Grid uses Angular's two-way binding. I would personally try binding the model to a "temporary" local variable using `editModelField` or a custom row template. Then have your afterCellEdit handler overwrite the "real" model when the change is committed.

You could package this functionality up in a plugin. There's a Yeoman generator for UI-Grid plugins: https://github.com/c0bra/generator-ui-grid-plugin . And this post has a how-to on using it: http://brianhann.com/write-your-own-ui-grid-plugin/

Comment: I feel like the temporary model solution should be embedded in the ui-grid-edit - the changes in the UI should not affect the model until they're committed. Thanks for the plugin links!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to join us in the gitter channel if you have more questions.